# Using SQL date Variable with TOAD

Tags: sql, date, variables, plsql, toad

I want to use a variable in TOAD for an WITH-SQL-Statement because today's date is used multiple times.

I tried with variable, DEFINE and Declare for setting the variable up but it didn't work yet.

Skript should look something like this:

```
DECLARE TODAY date := SYSDATE();

BEGIN
WITH

SUBQUERY1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.DATE = &TODAY
),

SUBQUERY2 AS (
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.DATE = &TODAY
),

SELECT *
FROM TABLE3 
JOIN SUBQUERY1 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY1.PRIMARYKEY
JOIN SUBQUERY2 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY2.PRIMARYKEY

END;
```

While researching I've read something about an into statement but I think it's used when you want to define the output of the query to the variable? Maybe someone can also provide me with an helpful article or so on.

Comment: Tip: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: Not my question... but thank you for raising my awareness to this. I've edited the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PL/SQL, just use a query (and make sure you have closing brackets for the sub-query factoring clauses and a comma between them):

```sql
WITH dates (dt) AS (
  SELECT SYSDATE
  FROM   DUAL
),
SUBQUERY1 AS (
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   TABLE t
         INNER JOIN dates d
         ON (t.DATE = d.dt)
),
SUBQUERY2 AS (
  SELECT t2.*
  FROM   TABLE2 t2
         INNER JOIN dates d
         ON (t2.DATE = d.dt)
)
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE3 
       JOIN SUBQUERY1 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY1.PRIMARYKEY
       JOIN SUBQUERY2 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY2.PRIMARYKEY
```

*Note: You do not need a variable for the date.*

In Oracle, a `DATE` always has date and time components (even if the client application does not always show it). If you want results for the entire day (rather than for the current instant) then use:

```sql
WITH dates (dt) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  FROM   DUAL
),
SUBQUERY1 AS (
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   TABLE t
         INNER JOIN dates d
         ON (   t.DATE >= dt
            AND t.DATE <  dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
),
SUBQUERY2 AS (
  SELECT t2.*
  FROM   TABLE2 t2
         INNER JOIN dates d
         ON (   t2.DATE >= dt
            AND t2.DATE <  dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
)
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE3 
       JOIN SUBQUERY1 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY1.PRIMARYKEY
       JOIN SUBQUERY2 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY2.PRIMARYKEY
```

Comment: I would spare PL/SQL but I need a variable. My code example is shortened and there should be the possibility to adjust the date manually to sth else then today.

I also just use TRUNC(TABLE.DATE) = TO_DATE('04.04.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY')

Comment: @Hisager Updated, define the date in a sub-query factoring clause before your two sub-queries.

Comment: This is also a helpful idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no improvement in what you did, not at all. What benefit do you see in using `today` in your code instead of `sysdate`? Typing 5 letters instead of 7?

Anyway:

- omit `&`, you aren't using any substitution variables here
- make sure open and closed parenthesis match
- `select` in PL/SQL requires `into`, so you have to first declare it
- beware of various exceptions, such as `no_data_found` and `too_many_rows`

Something like this:

```
DECLARE 
  TODAY date := SYSDATE();
  l_tab3_row table3%rowtype;
BEGIN
  WITH
  SUBQUERY1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE TABLE.DATE = TODAY
  ),
  SUBQUERY2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE TABLE2.DATE = TODAY
  )
  SELECT *
  INTO l_tab3_row        --> this
  FROM TABLE3 
  JOIN SUBQUERY1 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY1.PRIMARYKEY
  JOIN SUBQUERY2 ON TABLE3.PRIMARYKEY = SUBQUERY2.PRIMARYKEY;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND OR TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END;
```

---

Based on your comment, it seems that it might be a **bind variable** you need. It is "declared" directly in code, having its name preceded by a colon sign. Here's an example:

[image]

---

As of error you got:

> ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
>
> **Cause**: The database has been opened for read-only access. Attempts to modify the database using inappropriate DML or DDL statements generate this error.
>
> **Action**: In order to modify the database, it must first be shut down and re-opened for read-write access.

Comment: Yeah in my real code i have all the brackets and commas. The thing about the variable is because I have around 9 subquerys and there also should be the possibility to change the date manually to something else then today.

Comment: My Problem ist that I don't understand the PL/SQL into and declaration of into part. But if I implement it as you did I'm getting this error message: ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access.

Comment: I added example which shows what you might try to do.

Comment: Thank you. I've no allowance to change something on database level. But the bind variable is helpful indeed. Currently it's not planned to schedule the sql but if it is I guess the bind variable won't work anymore...